# Matching REST requests with responses in asynchronous server

Tags: rest, http, boost-asio

I have a Boost Asio/Beast based server that maintains a HTTP connection (keep-alive) to a REST service. My server listens for various commands, e.g. "send", "cancel", "ping". Requests are queued accordingly, and processed in an asynchronous manner.

When I read a response, I do not know how to match it with the corresponding request. For example, both "cancel" and "ping" may respond with empty strings, and as far as I know responses are not guaranteed to be processed in the order of requests.

Is there a way to match the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response ordering is guaranteed in HTTP/1.1.